# psql \copy command is not working on windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, command-line, psql

I have the below psql copy command which is working fine on linux server

```
export PGPASSWORD=****;psql -h "***" -U "***" -c "\copy (SELECT id, name,age FROM empschema.employee where id > 0 and id<=8238226) TO STDOUT WITH DELIMITER '|' CSV HEADER" dbname >/var/prod/test/first.CSV
```

Then I have changed export to set and tried the below command in windows:

```
SET PGPASSWORD=****;psql -h "***" -U "***" -c "\copy (SELECT id, name,age FROM empschema.employee where id > 0 and id<=8238226) TO STDOUT WITH DELIMITER '|' CSV HEADER" dbname >C:/test/first.CSV
```

above is not throwing me any error but it is creating empty file in the specified directory. Can anyone please help what I need to change in the command to make it work on both windows and linux

Comment: You can not combine commands using `;` in Windows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your reply. Then how  can I include password in the copy command

Comment: you need to run that on two lines

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes I tried it. It works but asking for password prompt in command line